# Почему происходит ошибка сегментации?

Tags: c, указатели, segmentation-fault

Суть задачи: Написать функцию с переменным числом аргументов, вычисляющую сумму
переданных чисел в заданной системе счисления. Примечание: десятичное
представление чисел может быть слишком велико и не поместиться в типы
`int`, `long int` и т. д. Для решения возникшей проблемы напишите функцию
«сложения в столбик» чисел в заданной системе счисления.

И казалось бы все работает, но если передавать в `amount` строки из 2 и более элементов,то программа крашится. Причем самое удивительное, что в дебаге все идеально работает.

Из мыслей было такое

```
char *amount = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char *) * 1000);
char *s3 = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char *) * 1000);
```

Но лучше не стало

**Помогите найти баг**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int digit_to_char(int num)
{
    if (num <= 9 && num >= 0)
        return '0' + num;
    else
        return 'A' + num - 10;
}
int char_to_digit(int chr)
{
    if (chr >= '0' && chr <= '9')
        return chr - '0';
    else
        return chr + 10 - 'A';
}

void reverse_str(char *str)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str) / 2; ++i)
    {
        char t = str[i];
        str[i] = str[strlen(str) - i - 1];
        str[strlen(str) - i - 1] = t;
    }
}

void swap(char* s1, char* s2,int* a, int* b)
{
    char *tmp;
    int t;
    tmp = s2, s2 = s1, s1 = tmp;
    t = *a, *a = *b, *b = t;
}

char* sum(char* s1, char* s2,int cc)
{
//    printf("12s");

    int ost = 0;
    int sum;
    int j,i;
    int n1 = strlen(s1),n2 = strlen(s2);
    if (n1 > n2)
    {
        swap(s1,s2,&n1,&n2);
    }
    char* rez_buf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char *) * n2 + 1);
    reverse_str(s1);
    reverse_str(s2);
    for (i = 0; i < n1; ++i)
    {
        sum = (char_to_digit(s1[i])) + (char_to_digit(s2[i])) + ost;
        rez_buf[i] = digit_to_char(sum % cc);
        ost = sum / cc;
    }
    for (j = 0; j < n2 - n1; ++j,++i)
    {
        sum =(s2[i] - '0') + ost;
        rez_buf[i] = sum % cc + '0';
        ost = sum / cc;
    }
    if (ost)
        rez_buf[i] = digit_to_char(ost);
    reverse_str(rez_buf);
    return rez_buf;
}

char* amount(int cc,int count,...)
{
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl,count);
    char* s3;
    char *amount = va_arg(vl, char *);
    char *tmp_value = va_arg(vl, char *);
    for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; ++i)
    {
        s3 = sum(amount,tmp_value,cc);
        amount = s3;
    }

    return amount;
}

int main()
{
    char* gg = "10";
    char* gg2 = "11";
    char* rez = amount(10,2,gg,gg2);
    printf("%s",rez);
    free(rez);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Буквы не обязаны идти подряд в отличие от цифр. Если это C, то у main-а другие стандартные параметры, если C++, то проблема с типами строковых литератов

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Проблема здесь:

```
char* gg = "10";
char* gg2 = "11";
```

Указатели `gg` и `gg2` указывают на *неизменяемые* строковые литералы. Изменение строковых литералов является неопределенным поведением. Вы их меняете в `reverse_str` и происходит ошибка сегментации — попытка записи в неизменяемый сегмент памяти.

Сделайте их массивами:

```
char gg[] = "10";
char gg2[] = "11";
```

Comment: Вы должны были получать сообщение от компилятора об ошибке  о невозможности преобразования const char* к  char*

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, в языке C (в отличие от C++) строковые литералы имеют тип `char [N]`, а не `const char [N]`.

Comment: не возражаю, но в вопросе стоит метка C++,  и можно допускать, что компилируется С++ компилятором